# What is meant by Galois twist or simply twist?

Tags: number-theory

What is meant by Galois twist or simply twist ?

I got a information as follows:

Let the Galois group be $Gal (\bar {\mathbb{Q}} / \mathbb{Q})$ and $X$ is a variety over $\mathbb{Q}$, then we say that $X$ has a Galois twist $X'$ if,
 $X$ is isomorphic to $X'$ over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Is it enough?

I need to understand it?

Please explain it.

Comment: You mean $X$ isomorphic to $X'$ over $\overline{\Bbb Q}$.

Comment: Like Dimitry [says](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285195/galois-twist-of-a-variety):"Just follow your nose". On the other hand, the word "twist" is used in different contexts, e.g., [Tate twist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate_twist), or "Dehn twist", etc. So "simply twist" in your title can mean different things.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, yes exactly, it was typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example: over $\Bbb Q$ consider the affine curves
$$C_1:\qquad x^2+y^2=1$$
and
$$C_2:\qquad x^2+y^2=-1.$$
They are isomorphic over $\overline{\Bbb Q}$; just make the substiution
$(x,y)\mapsto(ix,iy)$. But they are not isomorphic over $\Bbb Q$: $C_1$
has lots of points, $C_2$ has none.

Comment: Can you please explain Galois twist with an example? I want to understand it